# dbnSNP frequency anomalies

Tags: snp, 1000genomes

Sometimes dbSNP reports very different allele frequencies for different large-scale genome projects e.g. between 1000 Genomes and GnomAD

[rs11822440](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs11822440#frequency_tab) 1000Genomes A=0.4629    C=0.5371 GnomAD A=0.99997   T=0.00003

[rs28531832](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs28531832#frequency_tab) 1000Genomes T=0.4379    C=0.5621 GnomAD T=0.99993   A=0.00007

[rs78931618](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs78931618#frequency_tab) 1000Genomes A=0.7334    C=0.2666 GnomAD A=0.9999    T=0.0001

[rs75716913](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs75716913#frequency_tab) 1000Genomes T=0.9006    C=0.0994 GnomAD T=0.99149   A=0.00851

Is this an issue with one or other of these projects data processing? Is something else going on here biologically or technically that might cause this?

Comment: do you know what populations were used to calculate the gnomad frequencies?

Comment: These are SNP frequencies - its not the same thing as whole genome GC content. What we are looking at here is selection pressure at given SNPs

Comment: @user438383 the pattern is consistently different between projects in global and sub-populations e.g. African, European

Comment: @Michael these are the same SNPs with different frequencies for different projects - but both on "normal human" so I would be surprised if there is that much selection via recruitment.

Comment: The other thing - have you double checked you are comparing the same genome build between the two (i.e. gnomad is gr38 and 1kg is gr37)?

Comment: allopatry .. it happens

Answer (score 1):

I'll stick my neck out and simply state that allopatry alone would account for the pattern you are observing. Thus populations can exihibit variation in allelic profiles, particularly where Mendellian inheritance is operating (i.e. higher eukaryotes), singly due to geographic isolation.

This represents the Meyers view of population genetics and would account for variation within neutral theory, e.g. silent mutations. Obviously I'm guessing the populations were selected by geographic foci in generating the allelic frequencies.